# Simple sql function with SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I try to understand how functions work. I can make the equivalent in `procedure` but I can't create a simple function with `select`.

`element` is `UNIQUE` and
`thing` is `PRIMARY`

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
FUNCTION `get_element_by_thing`(`thing` VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
CHARSET utf8
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER

DECLARE @return_element VARCHAR(255);

SET @return_element = (
    SELECT
        `element`
    FROM
        `table1`
    WHERE
        `thing` = thing
);

RETURN @return_element;
```

I use the `phpmyadmin` interface.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `element=@return_element` here?

Comment: I want to return the `element`. Therefore maybe assign the `element` to the variable `@return_element` before return ?

Comment: Hint: That's not an assignment, that's a comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Don't declare user-defined variables.

The name of a local variable in MySQL stored program does *not* start with an at sign @. As an example:

```
 DECLARE stored_program_local_variable VARCHAR(255);
 SET stored_program_local_variable = 'somevalue';
```

The name of a user-defined variables start with an at sign @. (The at sign character is what distinguishes user-defined variables from other identifiers.)  It's not valid to declare a user-defined variable in a stored program. To create a user-defined variable, just assign a value to it.  For example:

```
 SET @user_defined_variable = 'somevalue';
```

2) If we don't need to persist variables beyond the scope of a stored program, we typically use local variables, which exist only for the duration of the stored program execution. (Which is different behavior than user-defined variables which are at the session level.)

3) Use the `SELECT ... INTO`  syntax to retrieve scalar values into user-defined or local variables.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html

---

Try:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
FUNCTION `get_element_by_thing`(`thing` VARCHAR(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
... 

BEGIN
   DECLARE return_element VARCHAR(255) ;

   SELECT t1.element 
     INTO return_element 
     FROM table1 t1
    WHERE t1.thing = thing
    LIMIT 1 ;

   RETURN return_element ;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Note: with ambiguous identifiers (i.e. routine parameter and column with the same name in a SQL statement, the routine parameter takes precedence over the column name. Qualify the column reference with the table name or table alias so it's not ambiguous. I prefer to assign routine parameters (and local variables) names that do not match column names.

If for some reason you need to assign a value to a user-defined variable in a SQL statement, you can use the `:=` assignment operator. This is also valid outside the context of a stored program.

```
 SELECT @user_defined_variable := t.somecolumn
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE somecondition
  ORDER BY someexpression 
  LIMIT 1
```